# Como subir carpeta target solo con war?

Tags: java, spring, git

Como puedo subir la carpeta target solo con el war ignorando todo los demas archivos dentro de esa carpeta?actualmente mi .gitignore esta asi:

```
/target/
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
```

dentro de target esta mi war que quiero subir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes agregar al ignore la lista de los archivos que quieres ignorar y dejar el target fuera, algo así como:

```
/target/archivo1
/target/archivo2
/target/archivo3
```